# Co-worker in another division is looking sick - don't actually know him, but wonder if someone should tell him

Tags: professionalism, health, colleagues

I'm not a doctor, but one of my co-workers appears very jaundiced.
I feel like someone should say something but I'm not about to for all the obvious reasons. I don't think it's any of my business, I'll just feel like someone should have said something if this dude ends up dead.

I'm not even sure anyone should say anything. What's the proper procedure here. I know jaundice in adults implies alcoholism, I just don't know what to do. I'm worried other co-workers are just assuming that it's someone else's role.

I'm not this person's manager, direct co-worker or even know his name, he's just on the same floor of a very big company and I see him around.

I'll probably just end up keeping my mouth shut.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you, I wasn't accusing though I can see how it would come off that way. All I meant was that I thought it made the situation even more delicate. But since I'm just going to keep my mouth shut anyways, I guess it's moot.

Answer (score 12):

Your plan is correct-- keep your mouth shut.

You're not seeing anything that this individual isn't seeing.  You don't know anything he doesn't know.  Presumably, your co-worker looks in the mirror at least a couple of times a day.  He knows what medical conditions he has been diagnosed with already and whether his doctor already told him to expect this.  He is perfectly capable of talking with a doctor if he is becoming jaundiced unexpectedly.  If he's been diagnosed with some sort of liver problem (I certainly wouldn't assume alcoholism though that is certainly possible), having random folks come up to him to let him know that he sure looks terrible aren't going to be comforting.

Comment: +1 - you also don't know what conversations this person has had with their team leader/department head/management

Comment: '*You're not seeing anything that this individual isn't seeing.*" Interestingly, a color blind individual would legitimately be unable to recognise some visual symptoms or early-warning sings like jaundice. ([Article 1](http://www.color-blindness.com/2008/07/09/color-blindness-in-medical-jobs/), [Article 2](https://changizi.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/the-color-blind-are-health-blind-but-it-can-be-fixed/)). That said, it's still not OP's place to bring this up.

Comment: Even if they aren't colorblind, it's surprising what people _don't_ see about themselves. For instance, I have a fairly large scar on my face that I swear appeared out of nowhere one day, but everyone else claims has been around for years.

Answer (score 0):

My policy is to leave people to their own problems unless it's my role to get involved.

However if I see people visibly sick I steer clear of them if I can, I have 4 kids, anything infectious I catch will affect my whole family. So I keep my distance and avoid shaking hands etc,.

This is probably the best thing for you to do.